# Safe way to cache PID to Port Mapping Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, sockets, winapi

I'm using [WinDivert](https://reqrypt.org/windivert.html) to pipe connections (TCP and UDP) through a transparent proxy on Windows. How this works is by doing a port-to-pid lookup using functions like GETTcpTable2, then checking to see if the PID matches or does not match the PID of the proxy or any of it's child processes. If they don't match, they get forwarded through the proxy, if they do, the packets are untouched.

My question is, is there a safe way, or a safe duration, that I can "cache" the results of that port-to-pid lookup? Whenever I get a lot of packets flowing through, say watching a video on youtube, the code using WinDivert suddenly chomps all of my CPU up, and I'm assuming this is from making a TcpTable2 lookup on every packet received. I can see with UDP there not really being a safe duration that I can assume it's the same process bound to a port, but is this possible with TCP?

Comment: Interesting question since Windows seems to reuse process ids sooner rather than later, apparently because of a subtle detail described in "When does a process ID become available for reuse?" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/01/07/10112755.aspx : basically, the process ids would be unique as long as somebody has a handle to the process.

The comments in that page are an interesting read. Seems you could control the validity of a PID by keeping a handle to its process.

Comment: @Luis thanks for the comment. Your suggestion about keeping a handle on the PID's is something I started thinking of after posing this question. It seems this might be, so far, my only reliable option. The question is, how expensive this will be. Unfortunately, some things that seem simple in the winapi end up being ultra expensive operations. I guess I might just need to try it. If you care to, post your comment as an answer. After doing some research, it much just be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, all I ended up doing here was using two std::unordered_maps. One map was to store the port number (as a key) and the last system time in milliseconds that the TCPTable was queried to find the process ID that was bound to the port (the key). If the key didn't exist or the last time was greater than the current system time plus 2 seconds, then a fresh query the to TCPTable is needed to re-check the PID bound to the port. After we've done that check, we update the second map which uses the port # as the key and returns an int that represents the PID found using the port in question on the last query. Gives us a 2 second cache on lookups which dropped peak CPU usage from well over 50% down to a max of 3%.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to Luis comment, I think that the application that *caches* the port to pid lookup could also keep a handle to the processes (just get it through `OpenProcess`). The problem, if that resources associated to a process are not freed until all handles to it are closed. That is normal, because until you have a valid handle to a process, you can query the system for various informations such as used memory or times. So you should periodically look whether the cached processes are terminated to purge the entry from cache and close the handle.

As an alternative, you could just keep another information such as the starting time of a process, that is accessible through `GetProcessTimes`. When looking in the cache to find a process id, you open the process and controls its start time. If ok, it is the right process, if not, the process id has been reused and you should purge the entry from cache.

The first way should be more efficient because you do not have to re-open the process for each packet, but you have to be more strict for identifying terminated processes to release resources, maybe with a thread that would use `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx` on all process handles to be alerted as soon as one is terminated.

The second way should be simpler to implement.